Hot to cast using Class returnType obtained through reflection?
I am using reflection to get return type of method which is String.
When I invoke function I need to cast return value to String.
How can I do that without explicitly using String and instead to use returnType obtained through reflection?
And why is this line not working. Isn't that the same as String.class.cast()
Class.forName("String").cast(method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40));

Main.java
//GET METHOD BY NAME & PARAMETER TYPES
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[] {String.class, int.class};
Method  method2        = personClass.getDeclaredMethod("sayHelloTo", parameterTypes);
    
Class   returnType = method2.getReturnType();   
        
String   hello1    = (String)          method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40);
String   hello2    = (java.lang.Strin) method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40);
String   hello2    = String.class.cast(method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40));
        
String   hello2    = Class.forName("String").cast(method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40));

Person.java
public class Person {

  public String sayHelloTo(String name, int age) {
    return "Hello " + name + ", you are " + age + " years old";
  }

}


do you mean returnType.cast(...)  ?! But that cannot be assigned to String variable since returnType could also be a different type - kind of defeating the reason to use cast at all.

How exactly it is not working? forName expect FQN, so use forName("java.lang.String") or just String.class.

It's not clear what you're trying to do or why. Isn't that the same as String.class.cast()? No, take a look at the return type of cast. If you already know you want to assign to a String, simply cast with (String).


And why is this line not working. Isn't that the same as String.class.cast()

Class.forName("String").cast(method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40));

No, because String alone (under the java.lang package) isn't a fully qualified class name. Most probably you would want this:
Class.forName("java.lang.String").cast(method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40));

However, you still need to cast it using the cast operator while assigning to a String. It's better to directly use the cast operator
String a = (String) method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40);

or describe what you are trying to achieve instead.

Still not working with java.lang.String

@ivoronline why you aren't directly using (String) method2.invoke(...)

I am trying to learn about reflection. I assume in real life I wouldn't know that it is a String. And therefore that I should use returnType to proparly cast return value. But I could be mistaken.

@ivoronline but (in real life) if you don't know it is a String, how would you declare the variable? (you cannot write returnType hello2 = ...)

So I was thinking about creating a Proxy that calls the method and returns its return type. So inside the Proxy I am not storing return value into String. Instead I am just forwarding it to however called the Proxy and that guy is storing it into String. Because that guy knows it is String but my Proxy doeans't necessarily know, it might be just chacking some input parameters or logging and then calling the Function and I want to make sure it is returning correct type.

@ivoronline But, how will you declare the return type of that method? It can work if you also take the return type as a parameter, which you probably won't want to do.

Minor correction: String is a valid class name. It just doesn’t refer to the intended class java.lang.String. If the OP insists on using the cast method, String a = String.class.cast(method2.invoke(personObject, "Susan", 40)); would be the way to go.

@Holger "What does 'String' refer to? I tried using Class.forName("String"), but it throws ClassNotFoundException.

It throws ClassNotFoundException because in your specific environment, there is no class whose full qualified name is String. But that doesn’t make the class name String invalid. You can easily create such a class, /* no package declaration */ class String {} So String is a valid name for a class. 123 would not be a valid class name.

@Holger Oh, ok, I misunderstood your reply. You are right; I will edit my answer.
